# MongoEngine - How to close a cursor

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm querying the DB using `timeout=False`

```
cursor = Users.objects.timeout(False)
```

The documentation says that if a cursor with no timeout was made, then it **must** be closed manually.

So, the question is how do I close the cursor after I'm done using it?
I didn't find any closing functionality in the documentation or in the cursor object.

** **Edit** **
This is the output of the `dir(cursor)`:

```
['_BaseQuerySet__dereference', '__bool__', '__call__', '__class__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getstate__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__module__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__' '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_as_pymongo', '_as_pymongo_coerce', '_auto_dereference', '_batch_size', '_chainable_method', '_class_check', '_collection', '_collection_obj', '_cursor', '_cursor_args', '_cursor_obj', '_dereference', '_document', '_ensure_indexes', '_fields_to_dbfields', '_get_as_pymongo', '_get_order_by', '_get_scalar', '_has_data', '_has_more', '_hint', '_initial_query', '_item_frequencies_exec_js', '_item_frequencies_map_reduce', '_iter', '_iter_results', '_len', '_limit', '_loaded_fields', '_max_time_ms', '_mongo_query', '_none', '_ordering', '_populate_cache', '_query', '_query_obj', '_read_preference', '_result_cache', '_scalar', '_search_text', '_skip', '_slave_okay', '_snapshot', '_sub_js_fields', '_timeout', '_where_clause', 'aggregate', 'all', 'all_fields', 'as_pymongo', 'average', 'batch_size', 'clone', 'clone_into', 'comment', 'count', 'create', 'delete', 'distinct', 'ensure_index', 'exclude', 'exec_js', 'explain', 'fields', 'filter', 'first', 'from_json', 'get', 'hint', 'in_bulk', 'insert', 'item_frequencies', 'limit', 'map_reduce', 'max_time_ms', 'modify', 'next', 'no_cache', 'no_dereference', 'no_sub_classes', 'none', 'only', 'only_fields', 'order_by', 'read_preference', 'rewind', 'scalar', 'search_text', 'select_related', 'skip', 'slave_okay', 'snapshot', 'sum', 'timeout', 'to_json', 'update', 'update_one', 'upsert_one', 'using', 'values_list', 'where', 'with_id']
```

Thanks.

Comment: Using the [`close()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.close/) method?

Comment: @roganjosh There is no close method

Comment: I don't understand, I linked to the official documentation showing that the cursor has a close method.

Comment: Here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.close/

Comment: Now you have two people linking to the exact same thing. If that doesn't work then you need to be more specific in your question about what's happening here.

Comment: In mongoengine's module the cursor doesn't have a close method..

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/CrPTP3Rye5I

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks! This answered my question

Answer (score 1):

Here using `del`:

```
cursor = Users.objects.timeout(False)
del cursor
```

This will notify the server to kill the cursor